# "What did he say?" or "What he said?"

Tags: questions, do-support, subject-auxiliary-inversion

> 1)  'What did he say?'
>   2)  'What he said?'

I am much confused about these terms please anybody explain 
       which one is correct and which I should use?

Comment: *What he said* is used to mean *(I agree with) what he said*, mostly in informal written English, to express agreement with previous post or comment. One could even write *What he said?*, but then it would mean that one is questioning whether one agrees with the previous post, or it could be an invitation for others to agree with it. But these are advanced and specialized uses which you probably don't have to worry about--although you will see *What he said* written by native English speakers all over the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What did he say?

forms a perfect question.

Natives may not opt for `What he said?` because it lacks the auxiliary verb 'did'.

To form a perfect question with ***'what'*** here, you need to put a verb (auxiliary).

See there, remove a question mark, and it becomes a sentence

> That is **what he said**.

This is the reason of adding an auxiliary verb.

---

If you are from an Asian country (especially India), it's okay to form a question like that. Asians understand this as a question. But don't practice it if you want to be good at the language. In India, I keep on correcting others whenever I get a chance! :)

Comment: I like the additional Asian Eng clarification. I'd never have thought of that, as a BrE.

Comment: I'm an Asian, too. I don't think it's really typical that way. I suspect that "He said what?" is more common among Asians.

Comment: @DamkerngT., sorry, I thought broader. Added! :)

Answer (score 4):

*What did he say?* is a question.  It asks for clarification of what he said if you have not heard clearly.

*What he said* is a statement.  It refers the listener to the previous statement that he made.
Adding a question mark does not, in itself, make it a question

Comment: *What he said* isn't a statement. A statement is a *complete sentence*, which requires a *verb*, and there isn't one there - it's just a [noun phrase](https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/noun-phrase)

Comment: What Chenmunka said. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @pazzo: Okay, smartass! :)  But I'd be *very* careful about encouraging non-native speakers to think that usage is "grammatical". It's a *very* recent idiomatic usage that's effectively shorthand for ***I agree with** what X said*. And let's not forget that I could have posted a response saying *What Chenmunka said?* (with a question mark) - disregarding pedantic issues about "standard, well-formed sentences", I assume you'd have interpreted that as a question meaning *What **exactly** did he say?*, or *What **specific aspect** of what he said are you expressing support for?*

Comment: Yeah, [basically](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56933/what-is-difference-in-these-two-and-which-one-is-correct/56935?noredirect=1#comment107929_56933). Idon't have a problem informing learners of idiomatic expressions that they will encounter.

Comment: @pazzo: Ah, right. I hadn't seen your earlier post. Which is a good comment, since it does alert readers to the fact that these are *advanced and specialized uses*. By implication, usages that might be idiomatic and/or ungrammatical and/or uncommon - certainly when I first joined SO it took me quite a while to get used to *What [previous poster] said* as a "standalone statement". At first it seemed more than a trifle weird to me, but I guess that's inevitable with many newly-emerging idiomatic usages.

Answer (score 3):

When asking a question about something that happened in the past, we use *did* with the bare infinitive form of the verb:

**What did you say?

When did it happen?

Why did the cost increase?

Where did the rain fall?**

But with *who* we use the past tense of the verb:

**Who took the book from the table?**

With *whom* we again use "did":

**Whom did he ask for directions?**

[Many native speakers no longer say 'whom' (objective case) but use 'who' instead:  "Who did he ask for directions?"]

An alternative, very informal way to ask such questions, a way which often expresses incredulity, or surprise, or impatience, or simply a desire to have your conversation partner confirm or repeat the statement, is as follows, with tonal emphasis on the final word:

You said *what*?

It happened *when*?

The cost increased *why*?

The rain fell *where*?

Comment: I have my doubts about associating past tense with *who* like that. It's perfectly natural to ask/say things like *"Who says I'm worried? I'm absolutely confident!"* (in that specific example it's probably a rhetorical question, but it wouldn't *have* to be). Come to that, there's (equally rhetorical) *"Who's your daddy?"*

Comment: But I'm not "associating past tense" with *who*.   My answer begins "When asking a question about something that happened in the past...."  Surely you wouldn't ask "Who *takes* the book from the table when I wasn't looking?*

Comment: Well, a teacher could certainly turn around from the blackboard and ask the disruptive class *Who did that?* or *Who threw that?*. I just think the issue here is the more general use of "do-support" to frame questions, and that present/past tense isn't really part of it. But I don't know how do-support relates to the "tonal emphasis" that distinguishes the standard *What do you want?* from the emphatic *Okay - you say you don't want that. What **do** you want?*

Comment: Your examples (who did..., who threw) support my position. You're choosing the past tense of the verb.  Throw->threw.  Do->did.  (In your example, "did" isn't a supporting/helper/auxiliary verb.)

Comment: My hypothetical teacher could also ask *Who knows the answer?* - I've given several examples, using present and past tense, with or without do-support. I'd also point out that there are perfectly ordinary contexts where *What **did** he say?* and *What **does** he say?* are to all intents and purposes completely equivalent. I just don't think present/past tense is directly relevant to OP's question.

Comment: Well, we understood the question differently. I understood it to be asking about how to form a question in the past tense, using *did* and not using *did*: `What did he say? What he said?`

Comment: How does past tense even play a role? Whether you ask about the past or the present, the use of do-support is the same, so why make any such distinction? You insinuate there is a difference between past and present that does not exist, which is potentially confusing. The fact that the OP asks a question about a past event does in no way imply that the answer should somehow only restrict itself to the past tense, especially since there _is no such distinction_.

Comment: @oerkelens: But there *is* a distinction; the present tense gets complicated by aspectual issues. It's not simply a matter of swapping "does" for "did". *Where does the rain fall? Where is the rain falling? Why does the cost increase? Why is the cost increasing? Who(m) does he ask for directions? Who(m) is he asking for directions?* So rather than complicate the situation, I limited the scope of the answer.

Comment: It's a very arbitrary limitation, because the same problems exist in the past. If you would simply limit yourself to _simple_ tenses (past or present) I can see your point. But I can throw _Where did the rain fall? Where was the rain falling? Why did the cost increase? Why was the cost increasing? Who(m) did he ask? Whom was he asking?_ at you to create the _exact_ same "issues" with the past as with the present.